# Hadoop Customization overwritten by Ambari - hadoop-env.sh

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2

It seems a simple task: change `JAVA_HOME` in `/etc/hadoop/conf/hadoop-env.sh` to use a different version of Java.

However, Ambari will, it seems, overwrite any changes you make in the hadoop-env.sh, by using it's templating scheme.

The template seems to contain following line:

```shell
export JAVA_HOME={{java_home}}
```

So, now if this is used to generate and replace the environment on each node, how do I define the `{{java_home}}`?

Comment: I'm very interested in this question as well since some weeks ago we experienced a similar problem: there was a Hadoop parameter that we need to modify and Ambari systemathicallly overwrote it due to its puppet scripts. The key point was such a parameter theoretically could be modified through Ambari (and it would be added to the puppet scripts) but did not work (do not know why...). In this case I think it is worst, since the Ambari UI does not allow to change the `hadoop-env.sh` at all and it must be touched by hand...

Answer (score 0):

As of Ambari 1.7.0, you can modify hadoop-env from Ambari Web UI. You can learn about the other features in Ambari 1.7.0, as well as 2.0.0 (which is the latest release) from the links on this page:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=30755705

Comment: How do I modify {{java_home}}, so I don't have to override in ambari? There is nothing wrong with the template itself as long as I can set that parameter somewhere.

Comment: You can modify the hadoop-env template in Ambari Web to not use the variable (just put in the path you want). But in general, that variable is retrieve from Ambari Server http://c6401.ambari.apache.org:8080/api/v1/services/AMBARI/components/AMBARI_SERVER, and ambari server got the setting based on what you choose re: JDK during "ambari-server setup".